# Open camera when app launches

Tags: android, android-camera

I am making an app that opens the camera as the background when the app launches, similar to snapchat. The code I am currently using has deprecated pieces in it and I don't know how to fix them. Any help is appreciated. My code is below.

```
public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;

public CameraView(Context context, Camera camera) {

    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    //get the holder and set this class as the callback, so we can get camera data here
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_NORMAL);
}

public CameraView(Launcher launcher, android.hardware.Camera mCamera) {
    super(launcher, (AttributeSet) mCamera);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    try{
        //when the surface is created, we can set the camera to draw images in this surfaceholder
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", "Camera error on surfaceCreated " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i2, int i3) {
    //before changing the application orientation, you need to stop the preview, rotate and then start it again
    if(mHolder.getSurface() == null)//check if the surface is ready to receive camera data
        return;

    try{
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e){
        //this will happen when you are trying the camera if it's not running
    }

    //now, recreate the camera preview
    try{
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", "Camera error on surfaceChanged " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
}
```

The issue is that these lines are deprecated.

```
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
mCamera.startPreview();
mCamera.stopPreview();
mCamera.release();
```

My Xml is below.

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Its only deprecated. That doesn't mean that it won't be work. Use `Camera2 API` if you want to use latest code.

Comment: how do I implement that, when i run the app, it doesn't work and the deprecated code comes up as an error.

Comment: What error it says ?

Comment: It says it cant resolve the method

Comment: What is minimum SDK version ?

Comment: 15 is the minimum sdk version.

Comment: Is there a library that i can use that will allow me to import deprecated methods?

Answer (score 0):

You have something wrong in your project setup or imports - the old camera API is deprecated, but that does not prevent it from being used in any way.

If your code snippet is *all* the code, you're missing package imports at least. If not, please post the actual error messages you're getting.

Android Studio may put up warnings, but that's it, if everything is set up right.